# Monogame ContentManager stopped working after NuGet install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, nuget, monogame

So I've been programming a game for in Monogame and so far it has worked wonderfully. I wanted to play around with the `IntermediateSerializer` class, which required me to install the `Monogame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Portable` package from NuGet.

After it was installed, I compiled my game and it suddenly stopped working. Everything that should be initialized inside Monogame's class `Game` is not initialized anymore (eg: `ContentManager`). Furthermore, the `Run` method from my `MyGame` object does not call Initialize, Update, Draw nor LoadContent. The program just exits without a window even opening.

I've tried reinstalling MonoGame onto my computer, reinstalling the package and cleaning the solution, but none of these worked.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 with MonoGame 3.6

PS: If I do a `git reset --hard` onto my project, it works again. It seems to be the package install somehow. The code works just fine if the package is not installed.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Monogame ContentManager stopped working after NuGet install

Not sure why installing the package `Monogame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Portable` will make your game stop working. To track the underlying this issue, you can open a new thread on [GitHub for this issue](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues).

**As a workaround**, you can manually download the nuget `Monogame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Portable` package from the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Portable/):

[image]

After download this package, rename it ending in `.zip`, unzip it. You can get the `.dll` in the lib folder, then reference this dll file directly to your project.

Hope this helps.